# ошибка Failed to execute 'createMediaStreamSource' on 'AudioContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStream'

Tags: javascript, web-audio

```
let srcAudio = document.querySelector('audio'),
context = new AudioContext(),
src = context.createMediaStreamSource(srcAudio)


console.log(src)
```

Что нужно наколдавать(как перевести данные с srcAudio в читаемый лад методом createMediaStreamSource) дабы решить проблему?

как я понял суть ошибки заключается в несовместимости данных srcAudio c методом createMediaStreamSource.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: createMediaStreamSource принимает MediaSource, а вы передаете туда html элемент. Можете описать, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: проблема заключалась в моей невнимательности, хотел использовать метод createMediaElementSource